# How can i avoid generated errors in pdf generation in laravel ( package: Barryvdh\DomPDF )

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation

I am generating a pdf file from a view but getting an undefined error of non-numeric value encountered with the help of package: Barryvdh\DomPDF. How can i just avoid this kind of error and just carry on with the process.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('view of pdf', [ 'data' => $data ])->save('path');
```

i want to avoid the unwanted error's generated in this process. As i am getting error which does not create problem in generating prdf but catching the error in try catch  and its stopping my pdf generating process. this is a problem with package i think but i want to bypass this problem

PHP 7.1.18

Comment: your question does not clear the issue. Please clarify it

Comment: which php version are you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` is the error suppression operator in PHP.

Try adding `@` before PDF

```
@PDF::loadView('view of pdf', [ 'data' => $data ])->save('path');
```

PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign  . When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.